# Javascript: td/tr element additional info

Tags: javascript, datatable

I need to provide additional information for my `td/tr` element. I've tried to make additional hidden columns (bVisible: false) but I can't pull them via javascript.

***Question:***

1. How can I set additional info to td/tr tags?
2. Why hidden field aren't visible via browser's console -> inspect element?

Comment: can mount a jsfiddler?

Comment: Hidden fields are available though dev tools/firebug. Can you give some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery to write/access custom attributes

Sample code

```
<table>
  <tr class='sample' scode='abcd'><td>Sample</td></tr>
</table>
```

In javascript method you can access it as below

```
alert($('.sample').attr('scode').val());
```

Comment: but how to put those attributes to datatable? I add my entities via `fnAddData` method

Comment: Like @Basha mentioned below, you can use Custom Data Attributes

Comment: the question is how to add those custom attributes via JQuery  datatable API?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Html5 Custom Data Attributes to store the custom data and can access it any time you want.

From the reference:

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to
>   the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate
>   attributes or elements.

You just have to use **data-anyname** as a  property to store any data.

Sample code

```
<table id="vegetable-seeds">
  <tr><td data-spacing="10cm" data-sowing-time="March to June">Carrots</td></tr>
  <tr><td data-spacing="30cm" data-sowing-time="February to March">Celery</td></tr>
  <tr><td data-spacing="3cm" data-sowing-time="March to September">Radishes</td></tr>
</table>
```

[Simple Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z2QCD/)

[Reference](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Comment: add access example please

Comment: @Volodymyr Bakhmatiuk Yeah sure, give me a minute please.

Comment: To get `data-foo` on some _HTMLElement_ `node`, if `node.dataset` is supported you can do `node.dataset['foo']`, otherwise `node.getAttribute('data-foo');`

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk Simple fiddle demo at http://jsfiddle.net/z2QCD/ Sorry for the delay, I have been busy

Comment: @Basha thanks! But how to put those attributes to datatable? I add my entities via fnAddData method

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk prepare JSON object and send it to the backend, there you have to prepare the sql and update the database.

Comment: @Basha I'm asking how to add `data-*` attributes to my td/tr node if I'm using jquery datatables. Means I use something like `datatable.fnAddData([id, name, sename])`

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk you can use jQuery attr() method to set and get the attribute